# Magento rewrite extension controller

Tags: magento, controller, url-rewriting, extends, magento-1.9

I am trying to do small change in community module MDN_Organizer in Magento 1.9 and it is turning out to be nightmare for me.

I need to change also one Grid so I created in code/local folders MDN / Organizer / Block / Task and new file Grip.php

For that, I have to rewrite one Action in controller TaskController which is in folder MDN / Organizer / Controllers / TaskController.php

Is it possible to rewrite that controller in local MDN / Organizer folder? Or Do I need to put controller to my own modules?

Can controller have the same name?
How etc/config should looks?

Controller is for admin.

Comment: What have you done in research so far? All your questions can be answered by just reading a tutorial on how to build a magento controller or how to add a column to the admin grid...

Comment: tutorials mainly show how to extends Core controllers. This question will help every new magento developer.

Comment: How you extend a 3rd party controller, happens in exactly the same way as extending a core controller...

Comment: Is it possible to extends it in the same folders in local as it is in community or core?

Comment: I do not understand your last question...

Comment: Original TaskController is in folders community/MDN/Organizer/controllers

I created exteded TaskController in folder
local/MDN/Organizer/controllers

What I should add to config.xml in local/MDN/Organizer/etc?

Comment: Yes, using the `before=` attribute and setting your overriding module in the local codepool! 2 second google: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/override-community-controller-in-local-codepool

Comment: In that example is another Module name. Original was Unirgy and new Guru. Is it possible to create in local modele with the same name as original and extends controller with the same name?

Comment: This is why I am advising you to follow a tutorial... In the example, the frontName `udpoadmin` of the community module has an ammendment/override in the local codepool (still for the frontName udpoadmin)! The modulename doesnt have to be the same... the namespace even has to be different... Overriding controllers does not work the same way as overriding models does!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new module you can keep in local or community it is not matter
But add code in you file

**app\etc\modules\Mycompany_Modulename.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Modulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <MDN_Organizer/>
      </depends>
    </Mycompany_Modulename>
  </modules>
</config>
```